# Interfacing a MIPI DSI dislay

Tags: power, circuit-design, display

I'm designing an interface board to connect a MIPI DSI LCD screen to an RPi. The screen is a `KWH070KQ40-C08` ([link to pdf](https://docdro.id/xay9SzM)), but the datasheet isn't quite clear and I don't get an answer from the company. I tried googling, but found no topic talking about interfacing MIPI DSI screens.

These are the pins with their recommended voltages. The datasheet only talks about current draw on the LED+/LED- pin (which is around `180mA`).

- LED+: 10V (Anode LED blacklight)
- LED-: 0V (Kathode LED blacklight)
- LCD_VGH: 18V (Gate ON Voltage)
- LCD_VGL: -6V (Gate OFF Voltage)
- AVDD: 9.6V (9.4V - 9.8V) (Power for analog circuit)
- VDD: 3.3V (Power for digital circuit (1.8V))
- VCOM: 3.15V (2.85V - 3.45V) (Common Voltage)

The board will be powered by a `5V` USB connection and has a `3.3V` voltage regulator. (not on schematic)

For making the `10V` (`LED+`), I plan on using a DC-DC switching converter (MIC2288), which may or may not be an overkill. Can I connect `LED-` with the ground or do I use a `0R` resister inbetween?

For `VCOM` and `AVDD` I was thinking on using respectively `+3.3V` and `+10V` and drop the voltage with a Schottky diode or voltage divider with buffer. But since I don't know the current draw I'm not sure what to choose.

Same goes for `LCD_VGH` and `LCD_VGL`, I could use a second `MIC2288`, make `24V` and shift it down somehow by `6V`. Or use 2 voltage converters for making `-6V` and `+18V`.

[image]

Besides the power pins, we have the 4 datapairs and clockpair. These I will connect directly. (not on schematic)

Lastly, the 4 `signal` lines.  `UPDN`, `SHLR`, `STBYB` and `LRSTB`, as there is no further information about these pins, I made room for a pullup and pulldown resistor so I test which one it is. (not on schematic)

[image: pin description]

[image: supply]

Comment: Just a note on power supervision here. All of these supplies should be "good" to allow the screen to operate. And is 28/29 really 1.8v? Yet another supply? Because this conflicts with VDD listed at bottom as 3.0v to 3.6v.  Your only choice may be to either experiment, or select a different display with a better datasheet.

Comment: @rdtsc added datasheet. And I had the same confusion as you. They say `VDD` should be `3.3V` but then they add `1.8V` in brackets. I think they regulate the voltage themself to `1.8V`, -as I don't see other `VDD` pins mentionned in the pinout.

Comment: It seems that the MIPI specification is a well-guarded secret. That is why the data sheets are so unclear. Not good for hobbyists. Did you make any progress? There is a youtube video series about interfacing the IPad Nano 6 display. It describes how this differential data stream is pushed.  But it's not a tutorial.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow Not with this particular screen. I've designed the circuit and am waiting for the PCB's to arrive. Luck would have it, that I had to design an interface board between a PIC32 and an LVDS screen for work. There I also used the TPS65150 and it works. Although we send the data in RGB format and use a SN75LVDS83B to convert it to LVDS signal. Do you have problems with something or need extra info? I know now what `UPDN`, `SHLR` are and how to use the reset pins. I'll have to test to see if they're active low or high though.

Comment: @Swedgin thanks for asking. I would really want to see a spec or tutorial because I want to hard-wire an interface to a cellphone display. I don't want to use an pre-fabricated interface adapter or FPGA, I want to drive the wires straight from breadboards. That is how I really understand how stuff works.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow What will you use to drive the display? In my project here, I'm designing my own dev board for a RPi CM3+. The hardest part will be to set the correct settings for the timings and everything onto the RPi.

Comment: @Swedgin, I am experimenting with display devices. I have a pixel stream (on/off) 256 x 256 or 512 x 512 at 60 Hz. I just want to pump it into the display. I really would only need monochrome right now, so it seems I need to clock it 8 times as fast in order to push color bits or so. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I ditched the seperate supplies and went with an all-in chip that provided the necessary voltages, namely the [TPS65150](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS65150) (`Universal, compact LCD bias Power Supply with integrated VCOM Buffer`). With a few external components I have my needed voltages generated from a 5V signal.